# Issue in using Facebook library project with Picasso library

Tags: facebook, picasso

I am using Picasso library for loading images. All was working fine until I started using Facebook library project. The moment I added Facebook library project to my application, Picasso library started showing error. It is not recognizing `com.squareup.picasso.Picasso`;

I am really not getting what is the exact issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced my Facebook library project with the latest one & everything is working fine.